# Exception when starting activity android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size

Tags: android, android-intent, transactiontoolargeexception

Creating intent with a large amount of data in extras

```
   public static Intent createIntent(Context context, List<PhotoItem> gallery, int indexOf) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, GalleryViewActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_INDEX, indexOf);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_OBJECT, new Gson().toJson(gallery));
       return intent;
   }
```

Then running the activity:
`startActivity(createIntent(...`

crashes application with error:

`Exception when starting activity  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size...`

How to avoid such errors when data is too large in the list?

Comment: You are passing whole `List<PhotoItem>` to your `GalleryViewActivity` with `Intent`. So it might possible that your list of `List<PhotoItem>` can have many data. So sometime system can now handle much data to transfer at a time. Might be the issue.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: But how to avoid such mistakes?

Comment: You should avoid to pass large amount of data with `Intent`. You can use `SharedPreferences` to store your array list and retrieve the same on other activity. If you need i add answer for you with more detail for this.

Comment: don't pass huge data between activities , also don't pass as a string  , create a parcelable implementation , or  use static fields or singletons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing whole `List<PhotoItem>` to your `GalleryViewActivity` with `Intent`. So it might possible that your list of `List<PhotoItem>` can have many data. So sometime system can not handle much data to transfer at a time.

Please avoid to pass large amount of data with Intent.

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store your array list and retrieve the same on other activity.

> Initialize your SharedPreferences using:

```
SharedPreferences prefrence =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = prefrence.edit();
```

> You can use this way to store list in Preference variable

```
public static Intent createIntent(Context context, List<PhotoItem> gallery, int indexOf) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GalleryViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_INDEX, indexOf);

    editor.putString("GallaryData", new Gson().toJson(gallery));
    editor.commit();

    return intent;
}
```

> Now in your GalleryViewActivity.java file

```
SharedPreferences prefrence =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = prefrence.edit();

String galleryData = prefrence.getString("GallaryData", "");
List<PhotoItem> listGallery = new Gson().fromJson(galleryData, new TypeToken<List<PhotoItem>>() {}.getType());
```

You will have your list in listGallery variable. You can retrieve your index as the same way you are using right now.